# Include global search in Laravel Validation

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

I want the 'name' attribute only to take alphabetic characters, numbers and spaces. It's all okay. I've tested it on http://regexr.com/ but when I run it using Laravel I get the "preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'" error

```
public function rules()
{
    return
    [
        'name' => ['regex:/([A-Za-z0-9 ])*/g']
    ];
}
```

I've been searching but all I get is a "use the preg_match_all() method" but how can I do that whithin this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g` is [not a valid PCRE modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in PHP.

That said, to only permit alphanumeric and spaces, you can use a rule like:

```
regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/
```

`^` indicates the beginning of the string, and `$` the end.

In situations where Laravel's stock rules don't cut it, you also have the option of [creating a custom modifier](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules) (where you could use `preg_match_all` to your heart's content).

Comment: Note: I took out the `()` from your regex, as they're not needed here.

Comment: Thank you! I created a custom validation and it's working like a charm!

Comment: @ggderas I'm not sure `preg_match_all` is what you want. It'll find alphanumeric/space characters, but it's not going to validate that the string is **only** those characters. Consider using the modified regex instead.